# Odoo 10 : how to change the state of workflow under condition?

Tags: odoo-10

I have this class:

```
class Custom_Project (models.Model): 

_inherit = "project.task"

task_lines = fields.One2many('task.line','task_id',string="Lines")

 state = fields.Selection((('draft',_('Draft')),('open',_('In progress')),('done',_('Done'))), default = 'draft', string='Status', required="True")
```

What I want is to change the state of the workflow to "done" when the value of the field "progress" in all lines of the one2many tree "task_lines" is equal to 100.

So in my custom module (in the .py file) I tried:

```
 @api.onchange( task_lines.progress)

 def progress_on_change(self):

  for record in self:

        all_done = True

        for line in record.task_lines:

               if line.progress != 100:

                   all_done = False

                   break

        if all_done == True:

               record.write({'state': 'done'})
```

But this does not change the state to done as I expected. What should I do to make it work?

Thanks,

Comment: You want to change state when mark = 100. Am i right ?

Comment: yes, state must change to 'done' only when all values of the field progress of every line in the one2many tree is equal to 100.